# why can't get the root of equation in R function solve?

Tags: r

x1=-1,x2=1,x3=1 is one of the root of the equation .

```
x1+2x2+3x3  = 4
4x1+5x2+6x3 = 7
7x1+8x2+9x3 = 10
```

why can't get the right root of it ?

```
a <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
b <- c(4,7,10)
solve(a,b)
Error in solve.default(a, b) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.7011e-18
```

Comment: The error message tells you why. Take a sheet of paper and solve this with Gaussian elimination and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the determinant of a is 0. You've got to specify the tolerance in your call :

```
solve(a,b,tol=1e-20)
[1]  0.1995899 -1.3991798  2.1995899

> a%*%c(0.1995899,-1.3991798,2.1995899)
     [,1]
[1,]    4
[2,]    7
[3,]   10
```

But, of course, that is one solution among an infinity of it...

Comment: It's not "almost 0". It's exactly 0. Calculate it by hand.